# How to use one loop if input is invalid for an if statement?

Tags: java, loops, if-statement, calculation

I am pretty new at coding in Java. I'm in classes now to study it and I'm having an issue with loops.

My assignment for this class is to write only ONE while loop for a program which calculates the weighted total of 3 grades. I'm using if else statements and a variable to declare what user input it should be on, however, if the input is not in a certain range, I need it to ask the same question again to the user. So far this only works with the first question, not the other two. How would I ask the same question again if the input is not valid?

Here is my code so far:

```java
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Lab3 {
    
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner scan = new Scanner(System. in );

    double homework;
    double midterm;
    double finalGrade;
    int i = 0;

    while (i == 0) {
      if (i == 0) {
        System.out.print("Enter your HOMEWORK grade: ");
        homework = scan.nextInt();

        if (homework < 0 || homework > 100) {
          System.out.println("[ERR] Invalid input. A homework grade should be in [0, 100].");
        } else {
          i++;
        }

        if (i == 1) {
          System.out.print("Enter your MIDTERM EXAM grade: ");
          midterm = scan.nextInt();

          if (midterm < 0 || midterm > 100) {
            System.out.println("[ERR] Invalid input. A midterm grade should be in [0, 100].");
          } else {
            i++;
          }

          if (i == 2) {
            System.out.print("Enter your FINAL EXAM grade: ");
            finalGrade = scan.nextInt();

            if (finalGrade < 0 || finalGrade > 200) {
              System.out.println("[ERR] Invalid input. A FINAL EXAM grade should be in [0, 200].");
            } else {
              i++;

              double totalWeighted = (finalGrade / 200 * 50) + (midterm * .25) + (homework * .25);

              System.out.println("[INFO] Student's Weighted Total is " + totalWeighted);
              if (totalWeighted >= 50) {
                System.out.println("[INFO] Student PASSED the class.");
              } else {
                System.out.println("[INFO] Student FAILED the class.");
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
  
}
```

Comment: Note: at the top of any loop for `while (i == 0)`, it's assumed that the condition is true, so the first if statement is redundant

Comment: I'm interested in your weighting (if could specify) as the final grade is already weighted being it having twice as many total possible points as each of the other two tests.  This means your `totalWeighted` could be simplified to: `(finalGrade  + midterm + homework) / 4)`.

Answer (score 0):

Your approach has many flaws, such as nested if-else, the while condition is invalid, and very poor indenting and overall code style.
Even if you changed **while (i < 3)**, and you entered an invalid value for let's say MIDTERM grade, your loop will be stuck in an infinite loop.

Have a look at improved code and try to understand it:

```
public class Main
{
    public static void main(String [] args)
    {
        final Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
        final String[] questions = {
                "Enter your HOMEWORK grade: ",
                "Enter your MIDTERM EXAM grade: ",
                "Enter your FINAL EXAM grade: "
        };
        double[] scores = new double[3];
        int i = 0;

        while(i < 3) {
            System.out.print(questions[i]);
            scores[i] = scan.nextInt();

            if(i == 0) {
                if(scores[i] >= 0 && scores[i] <= 100)
                    i++;
                else
                    System.out.println("[ERR] Invalid input. A homework grade should be in [0, 100].");
            }

            else if(i == 1) {
                if(scores[i] >= 0 && scores[i] <= 100)
                    i++;
                else
                    System.out.println("[ERR] Invalid input. A midterm  grade should be in [0, 100].");
            }

            else if(i == 2) {
                if(scores[i] >= 0 && scores[i] <= 200)
                    i++;
                else
                    System.out.println("[ERR] Invalid input. A FINAL EXAM grade should be in [0, 200].");
            }

        }
        double totalWeighted = (scores[0] * 0.25) + (scores[1] * 0.25) + (scores[2] / 200 * 50);
        System.out.println("[INFO] Student's Weighted Total is " + totalWeighted);
        if (totalWeighted >= 50) {
            System.out.println ("[INFO] Student PASSED the class.");
        }
        else {
            System.out.println ("[INFO] Student FAILED the class.");
        }
    }
}
```

Let me know if that helped :)

Comment: You could replace `int i = 0; while(i < 3)` with `for (int i = 0; i < 3;)`

Comment: What is wrong with my answer? If you give me a downvote, please explain why so. If you don't give an explanation, don't downvote me, my solution works perfectly.

Comment: Well, I didn't, but one reason is that it doesn't really help OP understand what's wrong with their own approach. Providing code to simply copy and paste without any explanation is generally discouraged

Comment: I improved my answer now. I am still learning on how to improve my answers, thanks :)

Comment: "very poor bracketing"? The OP's bracketing is fine. His indentation is horrible, but that could be unfamiliarity with SO's editing tools.

Answer (score 0):

So first thing, let's talk about your code formatting. It is so important to understand proper indentation when coding. Here is a link that may be able to help you out: https://exlskills.com/learn-en/courses/java-basics-basics_java/java-syntax-and-style-GTarpkcPunbK/basic-syntax-iCjqNivBnjcA/indentation-ukUQyypJUiKB
Not only does proper indentation help with readability, but with understanding the flow of the program. Please refer to my code snippet to see the formatting differences. You'll find your style with practice, but proper indentation is really big so be mindful of that (:

Now onto the code itself. You have the right idea going with checking user input before moving on. With just a few changes, I believe this is a simple, cleaner approach based on your original code. Take a look at this:

```
public static void main(String [] args)
{
     Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);

     double homework; 
     double midterm;
     double finalGrade;
     int i = 0;

     while(i < 3)
     {   
         if (i==0) 
         {              
             System.out.print("Enter your HOMEWORK grade: ");
             homework = scan.nextInt();

             if (homework < 0 || homework > 100)
             {
                 System.out.println("[ERR] Invalid input. A homework 
                 grade enter code hereshould be in [0, 100].");

                 /*if there is an invalid input error, then we can 
                 reprompt again without running the other questions 
                 using continue keyword */

                 continue; 

             } else { i++; }
          }     
           
          if (i==1) 
          {
              System.out.print("Enter your MIDTERM EXAM grade: ");
              midterm = scan.nextInt();
    
              if (midterm < 0 || midterm > 100) 
              {
                 System.out.println("[ERR] Invalid input. A midterm grade 
                 should be in [0, 100].");
      
                 continue;
            
              } else { i++; }
          }    

          if (i==2) 
          {     
              System.out.print("Enter your FINAL EXAM grade: ");
              finalGrade = scan.nextInt();
        
              if (finalGrade < 0 || finalGrade > 200) 
              {
                  System.out.println("[ERR] Invalid input. A FINAL EXAM 
                  grade should be in [0, 200].");

                  continue;
                
              } else { i++; }
          } 
      //end while loop      
     }    
                  
            
    double totalWeighted = (finalGrade / 200 * 50) + (midterm * .25) + 
                       (homework * .25);

    System.out.println("[INFO] Student's Weighted Total is " 
                       + totalWeighted);

    if (totalWeighted >= 50) 
    {
       System.out.println ("[INFO] Student PASSED the class.");
    }
    else 
    { 
       System.out.println ("[INFO] Student FAILED the class.");
    }

 //End main   
}
```

Now I added a lot of extra spaces in here, but I hope that helps you get a feel for the uniformity of the code spacing so that in improves readability. If you are not familiar with the continue keyword here, it is very simple. Here a link to help you: https://www.w3schools.com/java/ref_keyword_continue.asp

Comment: Dude, this is literally my answer from one hour ago :D

Answer (score 0):

You should make functions in this case and then you don't even require a single loop.
Use recursion.

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class Lab3 
{
    public static void main(String [] args)
    {
        Lab3 obj = new Lab3();
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);

        double homework; 
        double midterm;
        double finalGrade;
        
        homework = obj.hwGrade();
        midterm = obj.midGrade();
        finalGrade = obj.final_Grade();

        double totalWeighted = (finalGrade / 200 * 50) + (midterm * .25) + (homework * .25);
        System.out.println("[INFO] Student's Weighted Total is " + totalWeighted);
        if (totalWeighted >= 50) {
            System.out.println("[INFO] Student PASSED the class.");
        } else {
            System.out.println("[INFO] Student FAILED the class.");
        }
        
    }

    public double hwGrade(){
    
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
        Lab3 obj = new Lab3();
        System.out.println("Enter your HOMEWORK grade: ");
        double homework = scan.nextDouble();
        if((homework) < 0 || (homework > 100)){
            System.out.println("[ERR] Invalid input. A homework grade should be in [0, 100].");
            homework = obj.hwGrade();
        }
        return homework;
    }
    public double midGrade(){
    
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
        Lab3 obj = new Lab3();
        System.out.println("Enter your MIDTERM EXAM grade: ");
        double midterm = scan.nextDouble();
        if((midterm) < 0 || (midterm > 100)){
            System.out.println("[ERR] Invalid input. A midterm grade should be in [0, 100].");
                midterm = obj.midGrade();
        }
        return midterm;
    }
    public double final_Grade(){
    
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
        Lab3 obj = new Lab3();
        System.out.println("Enter your FINAL EXAM grade: ");
        double finalGrade = scan.nextDouble();
        if((finalGrade) < 0 || (finalGrade> 200)){
            System.out.println("[ERR] Invalid input. A FINAL EXAM grade should be in [0, 200].");
            finalGrade = obj.final_Grade();
        }
        return finalGrade;
    }

}
```

If you really want to make a loop, then you can use a do...while() loop.

Like,

```
do{
    homework = obj.hwGrade();
    midterm = obj.midGrade();
    finalGrade = obj.final_Grade();
}while(false);
```

This snippet is for main function.

Kindly comment if you liked it...